# Plex video problems on updated Chromium

Tags: pi-3, chromium

I have a Noobs RPi 3 connected to my TV. After a recent apt-get upgrade, Chromium is no longer displaying video from my Plex server correctly (it was working fine before the upgrade).

I get the audio, but the video frame is shrunk, duplicated four times with some garbled lines in the top-left corner of the screen.

Has anyone else seen this or know what the issue might be? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and update it with your comment. Then you can delete the comment.

Comment: I found the issue in this thread, by Silverlock on 4/10/19. Will see if his solution fixes my problem.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=236393

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by bumping up the GPU memory from 64 mb to 128.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=236393